# Desktop ram work on a server?

Tags: memory, motherboard

So presently I'm going out to build a fairly nice 8 core PC using older server parts, and I would like to know if I can use my desktop ram in the system. I have already looked this up, but I only find if server ram will work on a desktop. I want to know the other way around. My desktop has ddr2 800 MHz ram.
Just in case it helps:
the motherboard:
[https://www.amazon.com/HP-651907-001-Proliant-Enhanced-Motherboard/dp/B00AFYKZ92](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AFYKZ92)
The CPU(running two):
http://ark.intel.com/products/37096/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5506-4M-Cache-2_13-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI

Comment: No, you can't use your Desktop RAM. The motherboard and the CPU's use **DDR3**, DDR2 is completely different and will not work.

Comment: @GiantTree - I am not sure, I would say, "you can't use desktop RAM" considering the reason this specific example won't work is the face DDR2 and DDR3 are not compatible with one another which has nothing to do with "Server memory" vs "Desktop memory"  Xeon processor isn't technically just a server CPU, many people, use Xeon processor for home desktop

Comment: @Ramhound Well, let me clarify: He can't use *his* desktop RAM (the DDR2). I also think that this motherboard requires ECC memory (can't confirm, though).

Comment: @GiantTree - Yes;  I would agree it both uses ECC memory and it would be unable to support his DDR2 memory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You really have given me useful know age

Comment: The board requires ECC memory as well.  But it can accept ECC registered or ECC unbuffered memory (10600R or 10600E).  Per the amazon link.  Soe ven if you have DDR3 in a desktop board, you cannot use it in the server board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to build a server which uses a [HP 651907-001 Proliant DL160 G6
>   G7 Enhanced Server Motherboard System Board](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AFYKZ92) and install two
>   [Intel® Xeon® Processor E5506](http://ark.intel.com/products/37096/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5506-4M-Cache-2_13-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI)

Your underline question appears to be:

> My desktop has ddr2 800 MHz ram.  Can I use this memory in my server
>   instead?
>
> I would like to know if I can use my desktop ram in the system?

The **HP ProLiant Motherboard** only supports DDR3 memory.  DDR2 and DDR3 are not compatible with one another. They have different pin layouts.  You physically would be unable to install DDR2 modules into a DDR3 module slot without damaging your hardware.

Comment: I hope you understand that the motherboard you want to purchase is not a ATX motherboard.  This means it WILL NOT WORK unless you also purchase a hp proliant dl160 g6 server.  Based on the overpriced costs for the motherboard you are better off going with Xeon motherboard that is still supported by Intel.  You should stick with ATX hardware.  Considering the G6 server is a blade server.

Answer (score -2):

As GiantTree has said I can use my ram in the first place as it isn't compatible. Also after look back I realize this motherboard isn't what I would end up using anyways. (no SATA from what I can tell, but hey what do I know?)
Thanks btw

> "No, you can't use your Desktop RAM. The motherboard and the CPU's use
>   DDR3, DDR2 is completely different and will not work. – GiantTree 8
>   mins ago"